# How to assemble Python-bytecode to objectcode(for processors) on PythonVM?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that Python-interpreter converts a python-code into a python-bytecode, 
and can run the python-bytecode on PythonVM.

So, I'm interested in how to assemble python-bytecode to objectcode(for processors, ex. intel x64) on PythonVM. Does use assembly like `nasm` in PythonVM ?

I want to look at the code, doc, or reference about processing to map and convert python-bytecode to processor's instruction(set) code(follows: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/).

Please tell me.

Comment: Do you actually need reusable assembly separated from the python source, or is it more of a curiosity? [If it's curiosity, the pypy jitviewer might help](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/08/visualization-of-jitted-code.html)

Comment: @chew socks :Thanks, I especially have the curiosity, will search  pypy jitviewer.